# What is the reason for /etc/sudoers near line 23 error?

Tags: sudo

I fix that `/etc/sudoers` near line 23 error by using `pkexec visudo` command. But I don't know the reason. Can any one tell me the reason? And how to prevent these type of error in future?

My File Like this:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
Defaults !lecture, !tty_tickets, !fqdn 
Defaults !lecture, !tty_tickets, !fqdn 
Defaults !lecture, !tty_tickets, !fqdn 
Defaults !lecture, !tty_tickets, !fqdn 
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
```

I can Fix this problem by deleting Last Line. But Don't know the reason.

Comment: Show us line 23 (22, 23, 24 might be better) otherwise this is pretty impossible to answer.

Comment: # User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
Defaults !lecture, !tty_tickets, !fqdn                    Defaults !lecture, !tty_tickets, !fqdn                       Defaults !lecture, !tty_tickets, !fqdn                    Defaults !lecture, !tty_tickets, !fqdn       ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^

Comment: You should add it to you question and format it please (and use "more" not "cat" please).

Comment: Did you run a script that changes `sudoers`? If you did, whoever wrote it is an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

**Always use `visudo` to edit `sudoers`!**

To fix this, use `visudo` to remove

- the last line,

  ```
  ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^`
  ```
- and the duplicate lines preceding it.

  ```
  Defaults !lecture, !tty_tickets, !fqdn
  Defaults !lecture, !tty_tickets, !fqdn
  Defaults !lecture, !tty_tickets, !fqdn
  ```

  If it still gives you trouble, comment the only remaining instance of them (put `#` in front of it). I don't know what the users/groups `lecture`, `tty_tickets`, and `fqdn` are for, but they're not part of a default Ubuntu installation.

You were asking, how to prevent such a thing in the future:

- Don't edit `sudoers` without a syntax checker like `visudo`!
- Don't run [idiotic](/questions/587803/what-is-the-reason-for-etc-sudoers-near-line-23-error/588128#comment816126_587803) programs as super-user, that try to make unchecked changes to `/etc/sudoers`! Additions to `sudoers` should be made as new files in `/etc/sudoers.d/`.

Comment: Thanks David,
I Disable Password using this command. I thing it will affect for **sudoers.d** file.

sudo sed -i '26d' /etc/sudoers

sudo sed -i -e '26i%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL' /etc/sudoers

Comment: Did you read the very first line of my answer? Don't use `sed`, **use `visudo` to edit `sudoers`**! If you don't like the `vi` editor, set the `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` environment variable to your favourite editor (see `man visudo` for more info on this). If you want to allow password-less `sudo` execution, refer to [Execute sudo without Password?](/q/147241).